# Vimeo API get multiple videos in one GET request

Tags: react-native, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm in a situation where I need to make one GET request to Vimeo and get back info for multiple specific videos. Here is what I have for the query string currently:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/users/XXXXXXXX/videos?fields=uri,duration,pictures.sizes.link,download&containing_uri=/videos/ID1,/videos/ID2&per_page=2
```

Unfortunately, this only returns the information for ID2 and the video ID before it in its channel, instead of for both IDs specified. I've also tried appending multiple containing_url fields to no avail. Is there any way to make this happen? I'm using axios in react native if that helps.

Comment: What do you mean "ID2"?

Comment: Sorry, those are meant to be the video IDs. For example, if the ID were "261379936", it would pull this video: https://vimeo.com/261379936 - the XXXXXXXX is the user ID, as defined in the API documentation: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#GET/users/%7Buser_id%7D/videos

Comment: Understood, see my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "containing_uri", use "uris" as documented here:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#batch-requests
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#GET/videos

The "containing_uri" parameter will only return the page of the specified uri. The "uris" parameter will return the specified videos/objects. Your request should look like this:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/users/XXXXXXXX/videos?fields=uri,duration,pictures.sizes.link,download&uris=/videos/ID1,/videos/ID2&per_page=2
```

I hope this information helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!